# The possibility of tracking fingers with ZigFu and Three.Js?

Tags: html, three.js, kinect

I am currently using the Kinect for Windows and the `zigfu.js/three.js` library in an attempt to track a hand within a browser.

I would ideally like to create points on the fingers to find out their position.  I have looked around and I can't seem to find any hint as to whether this would definitely work.

I was hoping someone on here could perhaps point me in the right direction?

Comment: Any code? What have you tried? http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Comment: I have basically used the recipes so far and looked through the documentation but there does not appear to be anything that will help me to get information from the kinect regarding the fingers and I was just hoping someone could tell me if I am wasting my time or not.  I am not looking for a hand out just for someone to tell me if getting that kind of result would be possible with what I am using.  If it is not, then I will need to switch to something that would work like C#.

Comment: Can anyone on here help?

Comment: You question seems very specific, so it might take some time before someone who has the proper knowledge reply to you. :)

Comment: OK Forcemagic, I will wait and hope ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there is no facility in the Kinect SDK to tell you finger positions.

Long answer: the SDK is set up to do full body tracking, and at the ranges where full body tracking works best the resolution of the camera is so low as to make tracking individual fingers very hard indeed. Too much noise, too little signal, etc. You can see that just by looking at the raw depth data yourself.

There's no particular reason why fingers couldn't be tracked at close range, its just that no-one has done it yet (at least not in a publically available SDK form!)

Comment: WOW! thank you Rook!  Your answer really helps me.  After more digging I came to the same conclusion and although you are correct that no one has done it yet, I am not a strong coder nor do I have enough time to be that adventurous.  Thank you for taking the time to answer this question as I can now figure out a way to create my project without the use of finger tracking.